# loading 20 million records from SSIS to SNOWFLAKE through ODBC

Tags: ssis, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to load around 20 million records from ssis to snowflake using ODBC connection, this load is taking forever to complete. I there any faster method than using ODBC? I can think of loading it into flat file and then using flat file to load into snowflake but sure how to do it.

Update:
i generated a text file using bcp and the put that file on snowflake staging using ODBC connection and then using copy into command to load the data into tables.

issue: the txt file generated is a 2.5gb file and the ODBC is struggling to send the file to snowflake stage any help on this part??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ODBC is slow on a database like this, Snowflake (and similar columnar warehouses) also want to eat shred files, not single large ones.  The problem with your original approach was no method of ODBC usage is going to be particularly fast on a system designed to load nodes in parallel across shred staged files.

The problem with your second approach was no shred took place.  Non-columnar databases with a head node (say, Netezza) would like and eat and shred your single file, but a Snowflake or a Redshift are basically going to ingest it as a single thread into a single node.  Thus your ingest of a single 2.5 GB file is going to take the same amount of time on an XS 1-node Snowflake as an L 8-node Snowflake cluster.  Your single node itself is not saturated and has plenty of CPU cycles to spare, doing nothing.  Snowflake appears to use up to 8 write threads on a node basis for an extract or ingest operation.  You can see some tests here: https://www.doyouevendata.com/2018/12/21/how-to-load-data-into-snowflake-snowflake-data-load-best-practices/

My suggestion would be to make at least 8 files of size (2.5 GB / 8), or about 8 315MB files.  For 2-nodes, at least 16.  Likely this involves some effort in your file creation process if it is not natively shredding and horizontally scaling; although as a bonus it's breaking up your data into easier bite sized processes to abort/resume/etc should any problems occur.

Also note that once the data is bulk insert into Snowflake it is unlikely to be optimally placed to take advantage of the benefits of micro-partitions - so I would recommend something like rebuilding the table with the loaded data and at least sorting it on an oft restricted column, ie. a fact table I would at least rebuild and sort by date.  https://www.doyouevendata.com/2018/03/06/performance-query-tuning-snowflake-clustering/

Answer (score 2):

It should be faster to write compressed objects to the cloud provider's object store (AWS S3, Azure blob, etc.) and then `COPY INTO` Snowflake.  But also more complex.

You are, by chance, not writing one row at a time, for 20,000,000 database calls?

Comment: No I am not doing one row at a time, I am trying what you suggested I created a file using bcp command and trying to load using copy into

Answer (score 0):

generate the file and then use Snow CLI to Put it in the internal Stage. Use Cooy into for stage->table.  Some coding to do, and you can never avoid transporting GB over the net, but Put coukd compress and transfer the file in chunks